# How to pick out exactly the right string in my list of utterances?

Tags: python, string, numpy, pandas, nltk

So I am working on a python script using NumPy and Pandas and NLTK to take utterances from the CHILDES Database's Providence Corpus.

For reference, the idea of my script is to populate a dataframe for each child in the corpus with their name, utterance containing a linguistic feature I'm looking for (negation types), their age when they said it, and their MLU when they said it.

Great.

Now the user will be able to go in after the dataframes have been filled with this information and tag each utterance as being of a particular category, and the console will print out the utterance they will tag with a line of context on either side (if they just see that the child said 'no' it's hard to tell what they meant by it without seeing what Mom said right before that or what someone said afterward).

So my trick is getting the lines of context. I have it set up with other methods in the program to make this all happen, but I'd like you to look at one segment of one of the methods for populating the dataframes initially, as the line which says:
"if line == line_context:", is providing about 91 false positives for me!

I know why, because I'm making a temporary copy line by line of each file so that for each utterance that ends up having a negation, that utterance's index in the child's dataframe will be used as the key in a HashMap (or dict in Python) to a list of three Strings (well, lists of strings, since that's how the CHILDESCorpusReader gives me the sentences), the utterance, the utterance before it, and the utterance after it...

So I have that buggy line "if line == line_context" to check that as it's iterating through the list of lists of strings (a copy of the file's utterances by line, or 'line_context'), that it lines up with 'line', or the line of the kid's utterance that's being iterated through, so that later I can get the indexes to match up.

The problem is that there are many of these 'sentences' that are the same sequence of characters, (['no'] by itself shows up a lot!) so my program will see it as being the same, see it has a negation, and save it to the dataframe, but it'll save it each time it finds an instance of ['no'] in my copy of the file's utterances that's the same as one of the line's of only the child's speech in that file, so I'm getting about 91 extra instances of the same thing!

Phew! Anyway, is there any way that I can get something like "if line == line_context" to pick out a single instance of ['no'] in the file, so that I know I'm at the same point in the file on both sides??? I'm using the NLTK CHILDESCorpusReader, which doesn't seem to have resources for this kind of stuff (otherwise I wouldn't have to use this ridiculously roundabout way to get the lines of context!)

Maybe there's a way that as I iterate through the utterance_list I'm making for each file, after an utterance has been matched up with the child's utterances I'm also iterating through, I can change and/or delete that item in the utterance_list so as to prevent it from giving me a false positive c. 91 more times?!

Thanks.

Here is le code (I added some extra comments to hopefully help you understand exactly what each line is supposed to do):

```
for file in value_corpus.fileids(): #iterates through the .xml files in the corpus_map
    for line_total in value_corpus.sents(fileids=file, speaker='ALL'): #creates a copy of the utterances by all speakers 
        utterance_list.append(line_total) #adds each line from the file to the list
    for line_context in utterance_list: #iterates through the newly created list
        for line in value_corpus.sents(fileids=file, speaker='CHI'): #checks through the original file's list of children's utterances
            if line == line_context: #tries to make sure that for each child's utterance, I'm at the point in the embedded for loop where the utterance in my utterance_list and the utterance in the file of child's sentences is the same exact sentence BUGGY(many lines are the same --> false positives)
                for type in syntax_types: #iterates through the negation syntactic types
                    if type in line: #if the line contains a negation
                        value_df.iat[i,5] = type #populates the "Syntactic Type" column
                        value_df.iat[i,3] = line #populates the "Utterance" column
                        MLU = str(value_corpus.MLU(fileids=file, speaker='CHI'))
                        MLU = "".join(MLU)
                        value_df.iat[i,2] =  MLU #populates the "MLU" column
                        value_df.iat[i,1] = value_corpus.age(fileids=file, speaker='CHI',month=True) #populates the "Ages" column
                        utterance_index = utterance_list.index(line_context)
                        try:
                            before_line = utterance_list[utterance_index - 1]
                        except IndexError: #if no line before, doesn't look for context
                            before_line = utterance_list[utterance_index]
                        try:
                            after_line = utterance_list[utterance_index + 1]
                        except IndexError: #if no line after, doesn't look for context
                            after_line = utterance_list[utterance_index] 
                            value_dict[i] = [before_line, line, after_line]
                            i = i + 1 #iterates to next row in "Utterance" column of df
```

Comment: Consider separating the operations: first create DataFrame(s) from xml, maybe then merge/concat/reshape, then do computations. At the moment it's not clear (at least to me) which part your question is about... and mixing together xml parsing and computation makes for confusion!

Comment: Nick--is this a resolved issue? If not I can take a swing at it.

Comment: I resolved the issue, but probably not in an efficient manner, as I've done a lot of programming since the time I was working on this project.